# Help with writing in the past tense. What tense to use when showing a continuous future event?

Tags: tenses, past-tense

> Alden cleared the China from the breakfast table, smeared with bits of eggs and grits, and stacked them next to the sink. Just because she ***had*** a full time housekeeper, ***didn’t*** mean she ***was*** an animal.

In the second sentence, is it correct to say,

> Just because she ***has*** a full time housekeeper, ***doesn't*** mean she ***is*** an animal.

Am I overcomplicating? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why do you say "continuous future event" in the title. At what point in time is the person not an animal? Surely it's at the time of the events, which is their present, our past.

Comment: The first sentence is so wrong, I can't get to the second one.

Comment: How does having a housekeeper mean  you are not an animal? Perhaps you mean: isn't any animal. "Just because she has a full time housekeeper, doesn't mean she **isn't** an animal."

Comment: Do note that *China* is the name of a country, methinks it was *china* that was cleared from the table.

Answer (score 1):

It is okay to put the present in this case. That would express a thought Alden had at that particular moment which would be, for Alden, in the present tense. I would think the present tense would change the perspective from the author to the character, as if following his train of thought.

Using the past would also be correct, but that would distance the reader from the events narrated in the perspective of the author.